# App Preview video: the 5.5in video is not accepted by iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I can upload preview videos for all the other display sizes with no problem, but the 5.5in display size keeps giving me this error message.  The video format that I'm uploading *is* `.mp4`. I even tried `.m4v`, but the ear does not go away.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Just ot be clear: you opened that file in a hex editor and it begins with `00 00 00 14 66 74 79 70 69 73 6F 6D` (you can find those signatures [here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)). In addition to Oleg's suggestion, please consider filing a shadow report at [Open RADAR](http://www.openradar.me/page/1).

Comment: My signature is `0000 0018 6674 7970 6d70 3432`. The site that you mentioned doesn't seem to have the signature for `mp4`.  I'll file a bug report.